# Creating a branching process in R

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate a branching process (or Galton-Watson process) with a negative binomial offspring distribution. An example of a branching process is represented below, taken somewhat arbitrarily from [Cui, et al](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12918-018-0575-9).

Briefly, in the context of infectious disease, each branching process starts with one infectious individual (generation 0) and they infect a random number of secondary cases defined by some offspring distribution (I am using a negative binomial offspring with parameters (mean=r0, dispersion=k)). Each case in subsequent generations infects a random number of cases, and so on (i.i.d.).

[image: sample of branching process]

I imagine the data layout to be a matrix, similar to this this, which represents the first three generations in the figure:

```
#Example of data layout from first three generations in figure
x<-matrix(c(0,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,2,2,1,1,0,3),ncol = 3,nrow = 6)
colnames(x)<-c("Generation","Case Number","Secondary Cases (Z)")
```

I am unsure how to create a function that teases out the number of individual Z values. I have written a function that simulates a negative binomial branching process, but only sums the total number of cases in each generation (i.e. in the image below, G(0)=1, G(1)=2, G(2)=3, G(3)=4). Furthermore, in this function I have to define the number of generations ("n"), and a more accurate code would allow it to continue naturally until there are 0 cases in a generation.

The below functions provide some benefit to what I am trying to do, but have limited functionality.

```
#Single branching process
nbbp<-function(n, r0, k){
  # initialize return vector
  Z<-integer(n)
  #Initiate branching process with 1 index case in generation 1
  Z[1]<-1
  for (i in seq_len(n)[-1]){
    if(Z[i-1]>0) {
         x<-rnbinom(Z[i-1], size=k, mu=r0)
         Z[i] <- sum(x)
    }
  }
  return(Z)
}
#Simulate multiple BP 
nbbp.ind<-function(num_sim,n,r0,k){
    x<-replicate(num_sim, nbbp(n,r0,k))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized branching process function that can accept any distribution (`distr`) with an arbitrary number of parameters can be written as:

```
bp <- function(distr, gens = 20, init.size = 1,  ...){  
  Z <- list() 
  Z[[1]] <- init.size 
  i <- 1 
  while(sum(Z[[i]]) > 0 && i <= gens) { 
    Z[[i+1]] <- distr(sum(Z[[i]]), ...) 
    i <- i+1 
  } 
  return(Z)
}
```

Note `gens` sets the maximum number of generations to prevent overflow (can be set to `Inf` if desired), and `init.size` allows you to change the initial number of events in generation 0.

This returns a list of vectors, where each position position in the list represents a generation, and each position in the vector represents an offspring:

```
set.seed(12345)

# Negative binomial distribution
bp(distr = rnbinom, mu = 0.9, size = 0.25, gen = Inf, init.size = 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0

# Poisson distiribution
bp(distr = rpois, lambda = 0.9, gen = Inf, init.size = 1)

# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 0 0 1 0
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 0
```